# In Combine how do you make a publisher that sends one value but never completes?

Tags: swift, combine

In Combine how do you make a publisher that sends one value but never completes?

In the following code receiveCompletion gets called but I don't want it to:

```swift
Just(1)
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: {
            print("Completion: \($0)")
    },
        receiveValue: {
            print("Value: \($0)")
    }
)
```

How can I emit just one value but not complete...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be some better ways, but `CurrentValueSubject`, with never touching its `value`, would work as you expect:

```
let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(1)

publisher
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: {
            print("Completion: \($0)")
    },
        receiveValue: {
            print("Value: \($0)")
    }
)
```

Outputs:

```
Value: 1
```

Answer (score 11):

You can append `Empty(completeImmediately: false)` to any publisher to prevent it from finishing normally.

```
Just(1)
    .append(Empty(completeImmediately: false))
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print("completion: \($0)") },
        receiveValue: { print("value: \($0)") })
```